# computing the Kauffman bracket with the given relation

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

**My Problem:** Use the relation
[image]

to compute the bracket of the link diagram $D_n$ with $n$ components:
[image]

**My attempt:** It seems to me that raising the given equation to the $n^{th}$ power is the most sensible. (Note, that I interpret the power of a "knotted chunk," or the product of several of them, to be the respective connect-sum.)

So I would have

$$ \langle{D_n}\rangle = ((1-A^4)\langle x\rangle+A^{-2} \langle y\rangle )^n. $$

Is this correct?

Comment: Apply the relation to the left most clasp and iterate.

Comment: I was wondering if this is not exactly the same as my answer @CheerfulParsnip.

Comment: No it's not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close it off at the end, since if I understand what you mean, $((1-A^4)\langle x\rangle + A^{-2}\langle y\rangle)^n$ will just be a tangle.  So, you would expand this out, then close off $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle y\rangle$, giving $\delta$ and $1$, respectively, where $\delta=-A^2-A^{-2}$.

The relations you need are

- $\langle x\rangle\langle x\rangle=\langle x\rangle$
- $\langle x\rangle\langle y\rangle=\langle y\rangle$
- $\langle y\rangle\langle x\rangle=\langle y\rangle$
- $\langle y\rangle\langle y\rangle=\delta\langle y\rangle$

Notice the horizontal composition of the brackets of these tangles is commutative, so you can expand your expression out like a polynomial:
\begin{align}
((1-A^4)\langle x\rangle + A^{-2}\langle y\rangle)^n &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(1-A^4)^kA^{-2(n-k)}\langle x\rangle^k \langle y\rangle^{n-k} \\
&= (1-A^4)^n\langle x\rangle + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} (1-A^4)A^{2(k-n)} \delta^{n-k} \langle y\rangle
\end{align}

Hence,
\begin{align}
\langle D_n\rangle &= (1-A^4)^n\delta + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} (1-A^4)A^{2(k-n)} \delta^{n-k}.
\end{align}

That is, this is the bracket polynomial modulo any errors I might have made.

---

Another approach I like is to see what the clasp does to $a\langle x\rangle+b\langle y\rangle$ when attached to one side.  In the $\langle x\rangle,\langle y\rangle$ basis, this can be represented by the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1-A^4 & 0 \\ A^{-2} & -A^4-A^{-4} \end{pmatrix}$$
This matrix is diagonalizable as $PDP^{-1}$ with
\begin{align}
P&=\begin{pmatrix} A^2+A^{-2} & 0 \\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}
&D&=\begin{pmatrix} 1-A^4 & 0 \\ 0 & -A^4-A^{-4} \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Hence, we may take the $n$th power of the matrix by computing $PD^nP^{-1}$, which is
\begin{align}
PD^nP^{-1} &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \left(1-A^4\right)^n & 0 \\
 \frac{\left(1-A^4\right)^n-\left(-A^4-A^{-4}\right)^n}{A^2+A^{-2}} & \left(-A^4-A^{-4}\right)^n \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
The first column of this is what $n$ clasps does to $\langle x\rangle$, which is what we want to then close off to get $\langle D_n\rangle$.
Hence,
\begin{align}
\langle D_n\rangle
&= \left(1-A^4\right)^n \delta + \frac{\left(1-A^4\right)^n-\left(-A^4-A^{-4}\right)^n}{A^2+A^{-2}}\\
&= \left(-A^4-A^{-4}\right)^n
\end{align}